# how to change the working directory (execution path) in power automate desktop?

Tags: ui-automation, power-automate

I am using Power Automate to run an application. The application dynamically loads some dlls at run time. I'm getting the below error when it tries to load them.

"Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Power Automate Desktop\MyTestApplicationDAL.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Looks like Power Automate is using it's own installation path as the current working directory instead of the application that I'm automating.

Edit 1:
Here's a screenshot of my PAD steps.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What does your application do?  Does it need to just run and shut down or does it need to run and then PAD needs to interact with it?  How are you launching the application?

Comment: I'm launching it using the "Run Application" action. PAD needs to interact with it after launch. Some dlls are loaded at runtime from the application bin folder using reflection. That is when I get the above issue.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the run application action as you have it configured?

Comment: I have added the PAD steps screenshot to the question description.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for asking but can you show us the parameters/details of the `Run Application` step?

Comment: Sorry, I can't show that due to the company policy. It's just the name of our EXE file.

Comment: But that's important and I can't imagine that there's anything sensitive on it.  If there is, just blur/obfuscate it before you post the image.  On that step, there is a parameter for `Working Directory`, have you populated it?

Comment: Working Directory setting worked. That was excellent. I was new to this tool and completely unaware of that. Thank you for taking the trouble to help me.